# How to integrate Google Spaces with AWS CloudWatch?

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, google-chat

We are planning to move all Slack notifications to Google Spaces. I integrated the Google space with SNS through a lambda function for getting CloudWatch alerts. But the problem is I'm getting the alert response in JSON format in the Google space, which is not readable. I need the alert messages as we get in the Slack app. I'm using the below lambda function. Can anyone tell me how to send this JSON response in CSV or any other readable format to Google Spaces?

```
from httplib2 import Http
from json import dumps


def lambda_handler(event, context):
 url = "<webhook-url>"
 bot_message = {"text": event["Records"][0]["Sns"]["Message"]}
 message_headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
 http_obj = Http()
 response = http_obj.request(
     uri=url,
     method="POST",
     headers=message_headers,
     body=dumps(bot_message),
 )
 return response
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide more details about `iam getting the alert response in json format in google space which is not readable`? If you are using [Google Chat webhooks](https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/webhooks#step_2_write_the_webhook_script), JSON is certainly the expected format here, as can be seen in the docs samples.

Comment: You can use python card message in json. Follow this documentation.
https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/message-formats/cards